# In TypeScript, can I narrow a parameter type in an imported library, just within my project?

Tags: typescript

I am importing an external library in my TypeScript code. One of the types in this library provides a method `libraryMethod(x: string)`. I know that *within my project* only valid values for `x` are `'a'` and `'b'`.

If it was my code, I would have changed `x: string` to `x: 'a'|'b'` directly.

Is there a way to redefine type of `x` (without wrapping `libraryMethod` in another method)?

Comment: Declaration merging can't do this for you... The simplest solution is probably a postinstall npm script that modifies the declaration file for the library.

Comment: Given that `'a' | 'b'` is a subset of `string`, does it matter? What are you trying to prevent? `libraryMethod`, given its definition, can handle all valid values of `x` that your app can supposedly produce.

Comment: @TylerSebastian I'll give an example (*not* same as my case, but similar idea). In theory, `process.env['...']` can handle any `string`. But in practice, in my project I know that env can only contain `SETTING_A` or `SETTING_B` and asking for `SETTING_X` is a bug.

Comment: You can use a type guard to narrow the scope after loading the setting: `isValidSetting(x: unknown): x is 'a' | 'b'` (and, of course, actually do the check).